# Knockout Utility Functions - ko.utils.arrayFilter - data binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I found this tutorial for a knockout utilty that filters through an array and creates a new filtered version of the array.
http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

From there, I understand that the this.filter in  "this.filter().toLowerCase();" is the ko.observable bound to the input box in the view.

I tried to integrate this into my code. 
I am aware I need more changes.  The  method  "ko.utils.stringStartsWith" is not supported any longer

I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: this.kofilter is not a function"
I am not sure what that means, is there something wrong with the data binding?

This is my JS code

this.filteredItems = ko.computed(function() {

```
console.log(this)

var filter = this.kofilter().toLowerCase();

   if (!filter) { 
    return self.venueList(); 
         } else { 
                  return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.venueList(), function(venues) {
          return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(venues.name().toLowerCase(), filter) ;
      });
  }
}, this.venueList);



};
```

And this is the HTML

```
       <br><input placeholder = "Search..." data-bind="value: kofilter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
```

Comment: Post the line where you create `kofilter`. And indent your code correctly, that's impossible to read.

Comment: I found the issue, I was missing  self.kofilter = ko.observable('');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I was missing self.kofilter = ko.observable('');

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet it's yet again a problem with `this`. For instance I don't think you want to pass `this.venueList` to the computed as the context object, but rather just `this`.

If you have a `self` variable, stick to that, and don't use `this`. Otherwise make sure you pass the correct `this` argument to all the function calls.